# How to count occurrences of specific type in a list?

Tags: python, list

Is there an easy way to count how many elements of a specific type there are in a list?

This is what I have in mind and what I tried.

```
ex_list = ["string", "data", "item", 1, 3, {3: "im dict"}, "im_item"]

print(ex_list.count(int)) # -> 0, should return 2
print(ex_list.count(type(str))) # -> 0, should return 4
```

I know that there are workarounds (using loops, etc.) but I was wondering if there is anything as simple as using just one function (like count function, etc.).

Comment: There is no builtin function to do so. You must use a loop of some form.

Comment: `collections.Counter(map(type, ex_list))`?

Comment: Sidenote: `type(str) is type`, not `str`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class (from `collections`) with a mapping to types:

```
from collections import Counter

ex_list = ["string", "data", "item", 1, 3, {3: "im dict"}, "im_item"]

typeCounts = Counter(map(type,ex_list))
```

```
>>> typeCounts
Counter({<class 'str'>: 4, <class 'int'>: 2, <class 'dict'>: 1})
>>> typeCounts[int]
2
```

*This will do the initial counting in O(n) time and every use of `typeCounts[type]` will be O(1) thereafter.*

On the other hand, if you are only looking once for a specific type, you could do it with sum():

```
sum(isinstance(e,int) for e in ex_list) # 4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import countOf

countOf(map(type, ex_list), int)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxNCsIwEEb3OcWQVQLZSDYieAYPIFJCm2rAyQzTESzi2WMqXT34fh6v@qAajyytzUIIxFmSkkBBJlEY6VX1MhuT38OzLApnuNpFpdS7DWCnpGlj0YydhwAxwCeeeoIwlVHtd2tx@A9uxnB/qtutDhM7XTkH2PU@QO@9b@0H)

[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.countOf)

Benchmark:

```
 644 ns   646 ns   671 ns  countOf(map(type, ex_list), int)
2102 ns  2149 ns  2154 ns  Counter(map(type, ex_list))[int]
1125 ns  1150 ns  1183 ns  sum(type(x) is int for x in ex_list)
```

Benchmark with a 1000 times longer list:

```
 392 μs   396 μs   397 μs  countOf(map(type, ex_list), int)
 684 μs   696 μs   699 μs  Counter(map(type, ex_list))[int]
 854 μs   887 μs   896 μs  sum(type(x) is int for x in ex_list)
```

So for a "specific type" as your question asks, it's fastest of those methods, but `Counter` might be faster if you want multiple types (because once it's created, looking up a type in the `Counter` only takes O(1) time).

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVLBasMwDL37K0Sh2O4CW8kYW6Cn0fM@oJSSJWpniGPjqNAy9mf7hv1SJ8dJdikMxnRRIj1J70n2Z3pzbf7ow@WyD84CGYuGwFjvAkFAjyUJ0SEdPaxASil6mPMYSnJhBFbu2NLLPiUr1zRYkXFtN@afYx6DwNOuMR1xq82so2DawyyDWV1SGb0htOyXGeQZvOcFRyzUpqLZR8zaXQ/YikhDrGMTAWxymK5s6RWdPWYwzNEZmJa0zBJuYHEFpzeM24647mj7vDppMF1sAXvWeuKvqYKxWyE8SyAl8VRa3yDETCG1iOhdRIeyPaDKddE3jmGM4XX6j9Ye7SsG1rK8izbF4yE6Dne8PqxVuoRiyv0tsqFulRzzL/LtVJtYLZSc39fAR5AwB0VwOw5bwBKfdE@HIp1@Fu8Ktfgp15O6yGzg0zjWEyad6V3c8MMYD7tIQuRfV/D/@r8@ry/g4dcFXC7f)):

```
from timeit import repeat

setup = '''
from operator import countOf
from collections import Counter
ex_list = ["string", "data", "item", 1, 3, {3: "im dict"}, "im_item"]
'''

E = [
    'countOf(map(type, ex_list), int)',
    'Counter(map(type, ex_list))[int]',
    'sum(type(x) is int for x in ex_list)',
]

print('example list:')
for _ in range(3):
    for e in E:
        number = 100000
        times = sorted(repeat(e, setup, number=number))[:3]
        print(*('%4d ns ' % (t / number * 1e9) for t in times), e)
    print()

print('1000 times longer list:')
setup += 'ex_list *= 1000'
for _ in range(3):
    for e in E:
        number = 100
        times = sorted(repeat(e, setup, number=number))[:3]
        print(*('%4d μs ' % (t / number * 1e6) for t in times), e)
    print()
```

Comment: This is cool! Although IMO, this is more readable: `sum(type(x) is int for x in ex_list)`

Comment: @wjandrea Depends on the reader, I'd say. I'm used to using `countOf`, and also frequently use `map`. I find both equally readable. And I'm always thinking about speed (see the added benchmark results).

Comment: The advantage of `Counter` is that lookups are *O(1)* once it's created (which is *O(n)*). So this comparison is a bit apples-to-oranges.

Comment: @wjandrea Ha... I've already addressed that right under the benchmark, saying `Counter` might be faster for multiple types, but... I didn't think of saying **why**. The danger of being too familiar with stuff...

Comment: Ah yeah, true! My bad, I saw that, but I was thinking about situations where it would *definitely* be faster (like >2 types in a very long list) and not situations where it wouldn't (like <4 types in multiple short lists).

Comment: @wjandrea Yeah, back when I only had the "1000 times longer list" benchmark and Counter took less than twice as long, I even said Counter *is* better for multiple. Then changed to "might" after I benchmarked with the original list and saw those results, in case they do have many short lists like you say.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call a loop a workaround; any solution to this is going to use a loop, whether it's written in Python or under the hood. So, here's a loop solution using [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), which allows subclasses.

```
def type_count(iterable, type_):
    return sum(isinstance(x, type_) for x in iterable)
```

```
>>> type_count(ex_list, int)
2
>>> type_count(ex_list, str)
4
```

---

If you wanted to use [Alain's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69636126/4518341) [`Counter` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69636126/4518341) but allow subclasses, you could go through each type's [method resolution order](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order) (MRO), like this:

```
from collections import Counter

typeCounts = Counter(map(type, ex_list))
for t, n in list(typeCounts.items()):  # list() since the dict will change size
    for parent in t.__mro__[1:]:
        typeCounts[parent] += n
```

```
>>> typeCounts[int]
2
>>> typeCounts[object] == len(ex_list)  # This should always be true AFAIK
True
```

docs: [`class.__mro__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__)

Although, note that this doesn't support [abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class). For example:

```
>>> from numbers import Number
>>> type_count(ex_list, Number)  # 2 are `Number`s
2
>>> typeCounts[Number]  # but 0 inherit from `Number`
0
```